# Package Python script in virtualenv into a Debian package

Tags: python, linux, debian, virtualenv, package

I'm going crazy with this. I have a small script witch simply tells me the firefox profile name. As I said this is only a test, just for test how does it work until starting the real job. What we need is to deploy this script into a deb package to install them in all clients in our company (ubuntu mate).

I have to say that is the first time I work with python, so maybe the setup.py isn't correct either. I created a virtualenv in my izenpe folder, and installed a module with

```
pip install mozprofile
```

This is my folder structure:

```
izenpe/
  - izenpemiddleware.py
  - setup.py
  - debian/
      - compat
      - control
      - izenpemiddleware.triggers
      - rule
```

This is my izenpemiddleware.py

```
import sys
import mozprofile

def main(args=None):
    "The main routine."""
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]
    pro = mozprofile.Profile()

    print "Perfila da:\n"
    print "*************"
    print pro.profile
    print "*************"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And this is my setup.py (is it ok?):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

Description = """/
izenpe
"""

# setup parameters
setup(name='izenpemiddleware',
      version='0.1',
      description='Mirefox-en izenpe middleware instalatu',
      long_description=Description,
      packages=find_packages(),
      author_email='iibarguren@pasaia.net',
      classifiers=["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
                   "Development Status:: 1 - Alpha",
                   'Programming Language :: Python',
                   ],
      scripts=["izenpemiddleware.py"]
      )
```

I found this library https://github.com/benjaminirving/python-debian-packaging-example to generate deb packages from a virtualenv, so this is my config:

debian/control:

```
Source: izenpe
Section: python
Priority: extra
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), python, dh-virtualenv, python-all-dev
Standards-Version: 3.9.5

Package: izenpemiddleware
Architecture: any
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1), python2.7-minimal, ${misc:Pre-Depends}
Depends: ${python:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, python-pyside, python-numpy
Description: Izenpe ziurtagiriak Firefox-entzat instalatu.
```

debian/firefoxmiddleware.triggers

```
# Register interest in Python interpreter changes (Python 2 for now); and
# don't make the Python package dependent on the virtualenv package
# processing (noawait)
interest-noawait /usr/bin/python2.7

# Also provide a symbolic trigger for all dh-virtualenv packages
interest dh-virtualenv-interpreter-update
```

debian/rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@ --with python-virtualenv

override_dh_virtualenv:
    dh_virtualenv --setuptools \
    --extra-pip-arg --ignore-installed \
    --extra-pip-arg --no-dependencies \
    --use-system-packag
```

After that I generated a deb package with this command:

```
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b
```

Debian package is created correctly. I sent this file via scp to another computer installed with

```
dpkg -i izenpemiddleware_0.1_amd64.deb
```

If I `updatedb` and find the script with locate `izenpemiddleware.py` the result is:

```
/usr/share/python/izenpemiddleware/bin/izenpemiddleware.py
```

It seems that is installed correctly, but when I launch the script I've got an error:

```
root@portatil-001:~# python /usr/share/python/izenpemiddleware/bin/izenpemiddleware.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python/izenpemiddleware/bin/izenpemiddleware.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mozprofile
ImportError: No module named mozprofile
```

Am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup.py needs to state its `install_requires`.

```
setup(…
    install_requires=['mozprofile'],
    …
```